# Where are Visual Studio D365 Settings stored

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-dynamics

I'm looking for the folder/file/reg-Key or whatever where the D365FO-settings in Visual Studio are stored, eg

- *organize projects by element type*
- *preferred browser* pp.

Settings itself can be found via *Tools/Options/Dynamics 365*. While export settings via *Tools/Import and export settings* those settings are **not** exported.

Answer (score 0):

These settings are not stored in the same location as the other VS settings, thats why they are not exported by visual studio.

You can find the settings in the following location:

```
%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio Dynamics 365\DynamicsDevConfig.xml
```

[image]